# How to use React DnD with styled component?

Tags: styled-components, react-dnd

When wrapping my styled component in `connectDragSource` I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Only native element nodes can now be passed to React
>   DnD connectors.You can either wrap PaneItemText__StyledItem into a
>   `<div>`, or turn it into a drag source or a drop target itself.

The first suggestion from this message is to wrap my styled component in a `<div>`, but this will mess with my layout and would prefer not to do this.
I'm not sure what the second option is suggesting - would anybody be able to clarify?

Below is an rough example what I am doing:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { DragSource } from 'react-dnd';

const StyledComponent = syled.div`
...
`;

class MyComponent extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        const { connectDragSource } = this.props;
        return connectDragSource(<StyledComponent />)
    }
}

const itemSource = {
    beginDrag(props) {
        /* code here */
    },
    endDrag(props) {
        /* code here */
    }
};

function collect(connect, monitor) {
    return {
        connectDragSource: connect.dragSource(),
        isDragging: monitor.isDragging()
    }
}

export default DragSource('foo', itemSource, collect(MyComponent);
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use Styled Component's [**innerRef**](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#refs) to get the underlying DOM node, then you can call your [connectDragSource](https://react-dnd.github.io/react-dnd/docs-drag-source-connector.html) to it.

In your case, it should be like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
...
    render() {
        const { connectDragSource } = this.props;
        return (
            <StyledComponent
                innerRef={instance => connectDragSource(instance)}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

You can also look at my implementation of [Knight](https://github.com/zainfathoni/react-dnd-tutorial/blob/master/src/Knight.js#L39) component for the official chess tutorial as a reference.
It is also accessible through [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/zainfathoni/react-dnd-tutorial/tree/master/?module=%2Fsrc%2FKnight.js).

Comment: What if you don't need any connectDragSource? For example using styled-components on DragLayer.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using multiple connectors you can do the following:

```
<MyStyledComponent
  innerRef={instance => {
    connectDragSource(instance);
    connectDropTarget(instance);
  }}
/>
```

Source: https://github.com/react-dnd/react-dnd/issues/347#issuecomment-221703726