# How to use React DnD with styled component if the dragSource is also the dropTarget?

Tags: styled-components, react-dnd

I have already found this question
[How to use React DnD with styled component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50220622/how-to-use-react-dnd-with-styled-component/50446042#50446042)
but In my particular case, it does not help me, because my dragSource is also my dropTarget.

like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
...
  render() {
    const { connectDragSource, connectDropTarget, ... } = this.props;
    return (
      connectDragSource &&
      connectDropTarget &&
      connectDragSource(
        connectDropTarget(
          <MyStyledComponent>
            <h1>foo</h1>
          </MyStyledComponent>
        )
      )
    );
  }
}
```

So the question is: how can I use innerRef to call my connectDragSource **AND** my connectDropTarget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use component's `innerRef` to get DOM node.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    const { connectDragSource, connectDropTarget } = this.props;
    return (
      connectDragSource &&
      connectDropTarget 
        <MyStyledComponent
          innerRef={ref => {
            this.props.connectDragSource(ref);
            this.props.connectDropTarget(ref);
          }}>
          <h1>foo</h1>
        </MyStyledComponent>
    );
  }
}
```